# What Will be the Generic implementation of this Entity Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to Generic implement of the following query

```
double sum=context.Employees.Where(e=>(e.Id==12 && e.Sl==100)).Sum(e=>e.Salary);
```

i am using a repository system.
i want something like this

```
T total=GetTotalSalary((e.Id==12 && e.Sl==100),e.Salary);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing if `12` and `100` is hardcoded, this could be a good starting point:

Updated to reflect comments:

```
public abstract class Contract
{
    public decimal Salery { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeePermanent : Contract {
}

public class Employee : Contract
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Sl { get; set; }

    public void Test()
    {
        new List<Employee>().AsQueryable().GetTotalSalary(x => x.Id == 12 && x.Sl == 100);
    }
}

public static class QueryExtensions
{
    public static decimal GetTotalSalary<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) where T : Contract
    {
        return queryable.Where(expression).Sum(arg => arg.Salery);
    }
}
```

Comment: but salary will be different such that , Employee and EmployeePermanent . so arg.Salary also need to be a class type??  T:class ??

Comment: See the new update to my answer: create an abstract class (or interface) and make the extension use that one.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the variables as param to the function and use them in linq

```
    public double GetTotalSalary(int empId, double empSalary)
    {
        return context.Employees.Where(e=>(e.Id==empId && e.Sl==empSalary)).Sum(e=>e.Salary);
    }
```